# ASM skips Classes if COMPUTE_FRAMES is set in ClassWriter

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

I have been working on a Java Agent which is run together with the maven-surfire-plugin. The agent should be able to inject method calls using the ASM library into loaded methods at three different points: 1) In the beginning of each method; 2) At the end of each method; 3) At certain lines (see below). For this, I implemented a premain method that adds a new transformer to the Java instrumentation. The transform method is then creating a new ClassWriter and ClassVisitor (of the ASM library) for each class it should transform.

```
@Override
public void visitLineNumber(int line, Label start) {
    if(methodLines.first().equals(line)) {
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "de/ugoe/cs/listener/CallHelper", "raiseDepth", "()V", false);
    }

    if(mutationLines != null && mutationLines.contains(line)) {
        mv.visitLdcInsn(fqn);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(new Integer(line));
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "de/ugoe/cs/listener/CallHelper", "hitMutation", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", false);
    }

    mv.visitLineNumber(line, start);

    if(methodLines.last().equals(line)) {
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "de/ugoe/cs/listener/CallHelper", "lowerDepth", "()V", false);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have some trouble with it. If the `COMPUTE_FRAMES` flag for the `ClassWriter` is set, I do not get any errors, but some classes are skipped and not transformed by the agent. After some research, I found out that the reason for this is (most probably) the `getCommonSuperClass` method of the ClassWriter, which loads the class beforehand.

If I do not set the `COMPUTE_FRAMES` flag, I get `Expected stackmap frame at this location` errors, which I was not able to resolve.

Did anybody have a solution for this problem?

Comment: There is no good solution other then overriding the method with a non-class loading version and let ASM compute the frames. In practice, this is however fairly slow and cannot always be done as class files might not even exist at runtime or be unavailable. A more complex approach is to remap stack map frames such as Byte Buddy's Advice adapter does it. This does however only work when adding code at the beginning or end of a method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I somehow expected that this might be not easy to solve...

Comment: Can you give me a hint or source of information on how to write such a non-class loading version? I tried to find something but was not successful.

Comment: You can query the class loader for .class files. You can then query these class files using ASM.

Comment: Inserting simple `invokestatic` calls doesn’t change the code structure, hence, it should be possible while keeping the original stackmaps. Problems may arise due to the attempt to insert at source code lines. There is no 1:1 mapping between source code lines and bytecode locations, further, ASM report the lines using `Label`s, which may interact with the way ASM reports the stackmap frames (i.e. also using `Label`s.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49262105/2711488), ASM’s approach of calculating the (most specific) common superclass does not necessarily reproduce the stackmap frames of the original class. It does not only need to access the classes (which you could work-around), but may access classes, the original code never referred to, either because the original code used a more abstract type or an interface type or because the original frames actually dropped the subsequently unused value instead of declaring a merged type.

So the preferable approach is to calculate the stackmap frames based on the original frames, according to the code modifications you made. For your intended use case, that’s quiet easy, as you’re not changing the branch structure of the code but just inject code which leaves the stack state exactly as it was before the inserted code fragment.

So in principle, it should be possible to just use the original frames. To achieve this, don’t specify the `COMPUTE_FRAMES` to the `ClassWriter` and don’t specify `SKIP_FRAMES` to the `ClassReader`. You only have to adjust the maximum stack size if the original size was less than two, to ensure that there’s room for your method arguments.

The actual problems with your Agent come from the attempt to use *source code lines* for determining the code locations for inserting the calls. To illustrate this, consider the following example:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the following code to show, which ASM calls will be made to your visitor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader("Example");
    cr.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5) {
        @Override
        public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
            System.out.println(name+desc);
            return new PrintingVisitor();
        }
    }, 0);
}
static class PrintingVisitor extends MethodVisitor {
    final Map<Label,Integer> labels = new HashMap<>();

    public PrintingVisitor() {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5);
    }
    private String name(Label label) {
        return "label_"+labels.merge(label, labels.size(), (a,b) -> a);
    }
    @Override public void visitCode() {
        System.out.println("visitCode()");
    }
    @Override public void visitFrame(int type, int nLocal, Object[] local, int nStack, Object[] stack) {
        System.out.println("visitFrame()");
    }
    @Override public void visitLabel(Label label) {
        System.out.println("."+name(label));
    }
    @Override public void visitLineNumber(int line, Label start) {
        System.out.println(".line "+line+", "+name(start));
    }
    @Override public void visitJumpInsn(int opcode, Label label) {
        System.out.println(get(opcode)+" "+name(label));
    }
    @Override public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
        System.out.println(get(opcode));
    }
    @Override
    public void visitIincInsn(int var, int increment) {
        System.out.println("iinc "+var+", "+increment);
    }
    @Override public void visitEnd() {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
static String get(int opcode) {
    // for simplification, just the ones we need
    switch(opcode) {
        case Opcodes.RETURN: return "return";
        case Opcodes.ICONST_0: return "iconst_0";
        case Opcodes.ILOAD: return "iload";
        case Opcodes.IF_ICMPGE: return "if_icmpge";
        case Opcodes.GOTO: return "goto";
        default: return "<"+opcode+">";
    }
}
```

Which produces (when compiled with `javac`):

```
main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
visitCode()
.label_0
.line 3, label_0
iconst_0
.label_1
visitFrame()
if_icmpge label_2
.label_3
.line 4, label_3
.label_4
.line 3, label_4
iinc 1, 1
goto label_1
.label_2
.line 6, label_2
visitFrame()
return
.label_5
```

Which demonstrates:

- The “first line”, i.e. line 3 is reported two times, as the loop generates code at its end which is associated with the location of the `for` loop statement
- The “last line”, i.e. line 6 is reported before the `visitFrame()` that describes the stack state of the branch target of the loop end. The `label_2` is used for both, reporting the source code line and as target of the `if_icmpge` instruction. When delegating the `visitLabel` call to the `ClassWriter`, you’re defining the branch target and the branch target requires the stackmap frame, so there must be no code between the `visitLabel` and `visitFrame` calls, but the `visitLineNumber` call, which you used to insert code, is made right between them.

The solution:

- Inject code right at the `visitCode()` call for the beginning of the method. That’s before anything else happens and won’t conflict with any subsequent operation:

  ```
  @Override public void visitCode() {
      super.visitCode();
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "de/ugoe/cs/listener/CallHelper", "raiseDepth", "()V", false);
  }
  ```
- For injecting code at the end of the method, just use the precise instructions which can end a method, i.e.

  ```
  @Override public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
      switch(opcode) {
          case RETURN: case ARETURN: case IRETURN: case LRETURN: case FRETURN: case DRETURN:
          case ATHROW:
              mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "de/ugoe/cs/listener/CallHelper", "lowerDepth", "()V", false);
      }
      super.visitInsn(opcode);
  }
  ```

  Note that this is not sufficient to get a `finally` like semantic of calling the method in every case. E.g. when an invoked method throws an exception or the runtime generates it like when dereferencing `null` or dividing by zero, the method might not get called, but your original code had the issue.

For injecting code at arbitrary source code lines, there is no straight-forward solution. As shown, source code lines do not map 1:1 to bytecode locations and the reported locations might be at places where injecting is not possible. It’s much better to pick an additional criteria like an easy-to-identify code construct, for example, a known method invocation, to insert before or after it.