# "LinkageError: attempted duplicate class definition" when dynamically instrumenting java classes with ASM

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents, bytecode-manipulation

I wrote a javaagent by myself to dynamically instrumenting the java classes with ASM (I am not using the `COMPUTE_MAXS` or `COMPUTE_FRAMES` of ASM, I do that manually by myself). Actually, I am just trying to use a big try-catch block for non-constructor methods to capture the uncaught Exceptions or Errors and record such events (my code is actually the revised version of the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69549215/11495796)).

However, when I tried to use my javaagent in the testing process of an open-source project [joda-time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time), the following error occured:

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: org.joda.time.TestAllPackages
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "org/joda/time/DateTimeZone"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.joda.time.TestChronology.<clinit>(TestChronology.java:47)
    at org.joda.time.TestAll.suite(TestAll.java:37)
    at org.joda.time.TestAllPackages.suite(TestAllPackages.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3Reflector.createInstanceFromSuiteMethod(JUnit3Reflector.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3Reflector.constructTestObject(JUnit3Reflector.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:75)
    ... 6 more
```

To my understanding, each time when `sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader` is trying to load a class, the `transform` method of `ClassFileTransformer` is entered. The class is finally loaded after I modified the class and return the modified byte array. Therefore, every class should be loaded only once.

I further tried to print out the class name and the loader which loads it in the begining of the `transform` method, I found that `org/joda/time/DateTimeZone` appears only once, which is consistent with my understanding.

So now the only thing inconsistent with my understanding is the error. Why `sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader attempted duplicate class definition` with my agent? Every went so soomthly when I removed my `-javaagent` option.

Comment: In the code of the linked question, I can’t see anything suspicious. Since you’re introducing a dependency to `MyRecorder` in the instrumented class, it’s worth trying to inject just a `System.out.println(…);`, to see whether it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

To compute frames, ASM needs to find a common super class of several classes at targets of jump instructions. To do so, ASM loads the classes to browse their hierarchy. If you load a class this way while it is also instrumented during its first load, the class will slready be loaded post instrumentation and you will end up with this error.

To avoid this, you can override the getCommonSuperClass method of ASM's ClassWriter. You'd need to parse the class files of these classes passed to the method rather then loading them. If you wanted and out-of-box implementation of this, you could use Byte Buddy which exposes ASM and resolves its ClassWriter that way.

Comment: When the OP is still using the approach described in the linked question, they are not using the `COMPUTE_FRAMES` option. So this can’t be the issue. To my knowledge, circular dependencies aren’t resolved by loading it again anyway. Rather, you get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to load the class you’re just instrumenting.

Comment: Yes, I am not using `COMPUTE_FRAMES`, I'll add that information into the question.