# How to generate looping bytecode using Javassist?

Tags: java, javassist, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to write a compiler for an esoteric programming language that compiles to Java Bytecode. I'm trying to use Javassist to generate the bytecode.

I got stuck when trying to generate branching/looping code. For example, let's say I'm generating the code for:

```
while (true) System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

Here is my attempt:

```
var mainClass = new ClassFile(false, "Main", null);
var constPool = mainClass.getConstPool();
var mainMethodCode = new Bytecode(constPool);

int label = mainMethodCode.currentPc();
mainMethodCode.addGetstatic(ClassPool.getDefault().get("java.lang.System"), "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
mainMethodCode.addLdc("Hello World!");
mainMethodCode.addInvokevirtual("java.io.PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
mainMethodCode.addOpcode(Opcode.GOTO);
// I know that branch instructions take a PC-relative offset
// and after some trial and error, this seems to be the correct formula
var offset = label - mainMethodCode.currentPc() + 1;
mainMethodCode.addIndex(offset);

mainMethodCode.setMaxLocals(1);
var mainMethodInfo = new MethodInfo(constPool, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
mainMethodInfo.setCodeAttribute(mainMethodCode.toCodeAttribute());
mainClass.addMethod(mainMethodInfo);
mainClass.setAccessFlags(AccessFlag.PUBLIC);
mainMethodInfo.setAccessFlags(AccessFlag.PUBLIC | AccessFlag.STATIC);
ClassPool.getDefault().makeClass(mainClass).writeFile(...);
```

By inspecting the class file, I can see that the expected bytecode is generated:

```
Code:
  stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: getstatic     #12                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     3: ldc           #14                 // String Hello World!
     5: invokevirtual #20                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     8: goto          0
```

However, when running the class file using `java Main`, I get a `VerifyError`. I apparently need to add the `goto` target into a stack map (whatever that means).

> Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 0

I've found a `StackMap.Writer` class in Javassist, so I tried

```
var stackMap = new StackMap.Writer();
stackMap.write16bit(label); // does this add 0 (the value of label) to the stack map? 
...
var codeAttr = mainMethodCode.toCodeAttribute();
codeAttr.setAttribute(stackMap.toStackMap(constPool));
mainMethodInfo.setCodeAttribute(codeAttr);
...
```

However, the same `VerifyError` occurs when I try to run the class.

What is the intended way of generating branching code in Javassist?

Comment: I’d not use Javassist for this task but rather the [ASM library](https://asm.ow2.io/). It offers automatic stack map table calculation, but also an API for manual calculation (which I prefer). The advantage is that you will find more than one developer here who can explain how to do it. In contrast, most people using Javassist seem to rely on the “insert source code fragment” feature.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! Your comment was very helpful. I read through the user guide of ASM, and also the JVMS, and found a way to do it for this simple example. I will definitely be using ASM for my compiler :) Manually calculating offset deltas and frame types just looks painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Holger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71283970/how-to-generate-looping-bytecode-using-javassist#comment126019439_71283970), I was able to figure out that I actually needed a `StackMapTable`, not a `StackMap`. And I indeed need a stack map table entry at every branch destination.

```
var stackMap = new StackMapTable.Writer(0);
stackMap.sameFrame(0);
// ...
var codeAttr = mainMethodCode.toCodeAttribute();
codeAttr.setAttribute(stackMap.toStackMapTable(constPool));
```

Note that there are different types of frames, and they all say different things about the operand stack, and what local variables are available. `sameFrame` is the type that indicates that the local variables are the same as the previous frame, and the operand stack is empty. Other types include `appendFrame`, `chopFrame`, `fullFrame`. For more info, see [JVMS 4.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.4).

In general, the argument `0` passed to `sameFrame` is not the bytecode offset at which I want the stack map table entry to apply to. Rather, it is the "offset delta". The bytecode offset that the entry applies to is computed by adding (offset delta + 1) to the bytecode offset that the previous frame applies to. *Only for the first frame,* is the offset delta same as the bytecode offset to which it applies.

It seems like the [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io) library is more suitable for bytecode generation like this. I don't need to calculate the PC offsets manually. It even has the option (`COMPUTE_FRAMES`) to work out which type of frame you should use, at the cost of performance.

```
var cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

cw.visit(V1_6,
    ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_SUPER,
    "Main",
    null,
    "java/lang/Object",
    null);

cw.visitSource("Main.java", null);
var mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC,
    "main",
    "([Ljava/lang/String;)V",
    null,
    null);
mv.visitCode();
var start = new Label();
mv.visitLabel(start);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC,
    "java/lang/System",
    "out",
    "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
mv.visitLdcInsn("Hello World!");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
    "java/io/PrintStream",
    "println",
    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
    false);
mv.visitJumpInsn(GOTO, start);
mv.visitMaxs(0, 0);
mv.visitEnd();
cw.visitEnd();
var bytes = cw.toByteArray();
var stream = new FileOutputStream("...");
stream.write(bytes);
stream.close();
```

Comment: Right, with ASM you don’t need to calculate offsets as you use `Label` like with the branch instructions. Further, the different frame types are only a code size optimization. When in doubt, you can always use `FULL_FRAME`. When you’re implementing a compiler, you should have an idea about the stack frame at any time anyway, which makes it easy to provide the frame explicitly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49262105/2711488) for a detailed discussion of the issues with calculating frames by inference. By the way, write the result with a single `Files.write(Path.of("…"), bytes);`